# How do I mock validation in domain class for testing?

Tags: validation, unit-testing, grails

I have a domain class that uses a custom validator that's quite complex; it requires a separate collaborator. Now I'm creating a controller for it but I want to mock the part about validation. I want to be able to tell when a certain validation error occurs so that I control the behavior.

For example, I have,

```
class Person {

    static constraint = {
        key validator: {
            //complex stuff goes here
        }
    }

}
```

In my controller spec, I want to be able to tell when I want the validation to pass or to fail. I tried doing `Person.metaClass.validate = { true }` but it doesn't seem to work. This is how my test code looks like.

```
void "Test controller when validation passes"() {
    when:
    controller.json = new Person(...)
    controller.doSomething()

    then:
    //test post condition, etc.
}
```

If nothing works, I'm thinking of just mocking the command object directly, something like,

```
void "Test controller when validation passes"() {
    when:
    controller.doSomething(Mock(Person))

    then:
    1 * _.changeState(_)
    //test post condition, etc.
}
```

but if I can get the first one working, I'd prefer it more.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar tasks in my Project. Our implementation includes *ErrorsContainer* class that represents the concept of  [Mediator design pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-mediator) by encapsulating how a set of objects interact. Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently.

Another advantage of this approach is that you can *cache* the result of the validation process. When applied to same preconditions, objects and rulles - it can improve the performance.

About the

> I want to be able to tell when I want the validation to pass or to fail

you can just call it's `isEmpty()` and use it in simple code like this:

```
public class ValidationProcessor {
    private ErrorsContainer errorsContainer;

    //process Validation 

    ........

    //if validation errors are found add them 
    //into the container

    ........

    //allow to manage the Validation process
    public void SetValidationState(boolean isPassState){
        if(isPassState){
           //set it's state to 'pass'
           errorsContainer.setEmpty();
        }else{
          //apply logic when validation errors are found 
        }
    }

    public void UseCurrentValidationState(){
        if(errorsContainer.isEmpty()){
           //apply logic when no validation errors are found
        }else{
          //apply logic when validation errors are found 
        }
    }
}
```